# onClick event in a For loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I've tried to create a loop with `for`, and increment by an onclick event, but it doesn't work.

```
var gameCase = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],  // 9
    itemLists = $('game').getElementsByTagName('li'); // 9 items

for( var i = 0; i < itemLists.length; i++ ) {
     // i already equals 9
     itemLists[i].onclick = function() {
          // do something
    }
 }
```

But in this case, the `for` loop is finished before I was able to click on an element in the list.

Moreover, I would like to get the item list I clicked and save it in an array. I tried `gameCase[this]` (in onclick function), but I don't know if it's the good way.

Comment: What is `$('game').getElementsByTagName('li');`, You use jQuery or pure javascript here?

Comment: @user1479606 Pure javascript, I just created my own selector.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

John Resig covers this topic very well in "Secrets of the JavaScript Ninja" ( http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#59 )

You'll need to create a temporary scope to preserve i's value

```
for ( var i = 0; i < itemLists.length; i++ ) (function(i){ 
  itemLists[i].onclick = function() {
      // do something
  }
})(i);
```

Edit:

```
var gameCase = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], // 9
$listParent = $('game').find('ul'), // li's parent
itemLists = $('game').getElementsByTagName('li'); // 9 items

var listHandler = (function() {
  var i = 0;

  return function() {
    // $(this) will in here refer to the clicked li
    i++ // increment i

    if ( i === 9 ) {
      $listParent.off('click', 'li', listHandler); //remove eventhandler when i reaches 9
    }
  }
}());

$listParent.on('click', 'li', listHandler); // attach eventhandler to ul element
```

This should do what you want, cant test it right now since I'm at work.

Comment: As @Tim van Elsloo tell, it's the good way. But there is just something weird, when I console.log the value of the i before I click on any items of my list, the i value decrease. 

`for ( var i = 0; i < itemLists.length; i++ ) (function(i){
  console.log(i); //0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
  itemLists[i].onclick = function() {
     // i egal to 4 if I clicked on the third element.
  }
})(i);`

Comment: The length property starts from 1 and your i var from 0. So you'd either have to change the for loop to start from 1 and end on length+1 or change inside the function to itemLists[i+1].onclick.

Comment: Yes, I know, that's not the problem. The interest of the Loop, is when i is egal to 9, I can't do nothing more. But right here, the For loop is already finished, before I click on an element. I would like, when I click on an item of my list, i increment, and when I arrived to 9, the loop stops.

Comment: Ok so you just want to increment i every time a listItem is clicked? In that case you dont want a for loop at all. What this does is immediately loop i from 0 to 9 and add an eventhandler to each itemlist. I'll edit my answer with what I think you need when I understand you correctly

Comment: Yes, that's what I would like to have.

Comment: Ok, edited my answer with a script that will increment i each time a li element is clicked and when it reaches 9 removes the eventhandler. Pretty sure that I misunderstood your problem again. Would be easier if you posted a jsfiddle with your code and what exactly your trying to achieve.

Comment: I don't use jQuery, $('') is just my own selector to document.getElementByID(''). I tried your script, it's the way I am looking for, but it doesn't work yet. Here is a little jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/4Rjp9/

Comment: Oh and for future reference you might want to look into binding the eventhandlers in a better way since DOM level 0 is pretty outdated and considered bad practice.

Comment: I spent a week dealing with this issue. Never new anything about doing it this way.

Answer (score 11):

Wrap your listener:

```
onclick = (function(i) {return function() {
    ...
};})(i);
```

This fixes your variable scope issues.

Comment: That's quite good, when I cliked on a list item, it returns the good number of the case. But is it okay, that the For loop increment before I start to click ?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if I did not understand your question properly,
From the code I understand that, you are trying to add an onclick handler to all the list elements in found in the game tag (perhaps it should be a class / id).

The for loop will be executed when the script tag / file loads without any user interaction.

If you wish to assign a function that uses the current value of the counter. Use the following code:

```
itemLists[i].onclick = (function() {
    return function() {
         // TODO ---
        // Your handler code here
}
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use a forEach loop this creates a new variable for each iteration.

```
var gameCase = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], // 9
itemLists = $('game').getElementsByTagName('li'); // 9 items

itemLists.forEach(function(item,index){
    item.onclick = function() {
      // do something
 }
});
```