# onclick event in a for loop certain amount of times

Tags: javascript, html

I thought that this [onClick event in a For loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15860683/onclick-event-in-a-for-loop) would help me but when I tried it, it still didn't work.

I am making a simple Battleship game, and while I'm trying to have the user click on only 4 squares to place on ship, the loop keeps going and doesn't stop after 4 tries. I have my onclick even handler in a for loop, but after 4 tries it doesn't stop. I've tried adding a count variable after the end, and even tried adding a break statement but can't get it to work.

Here's my code:

```
    function placeShips() {
        var playerTable = document.getElementById("mainPlayer");
        var playerCells = playerTable.getElementsByTagName("td");
        var count = 1;

        alert("Please place the first ship. Click on 4 squares.");
        while (count <= 4) {
            for (i = 0; i < playerCells.length; i++) {
                playerCells[i].onclick = placeBattleship;
            }
            count++;
        }
    }
```

The `placeBattleship` function contains the code to change the grid square to a background color of red to mark it. My problem is that once the user clicks 4 squares, you can keep going and click on more and more. I can't get the above for loop that calls the placeBattleship function to stop after the user clicks on 4 squares. I've tried putting it in a while loop, and even the solution in the above link, as well as moving the assignment of count, but can't get it to stop after x amount of times (in this case, 4).

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong, or a better way to do it?

Comment: Every time you run the loop you are resetting count to 1

Comment: OP. Aren't you just attaching placeBattleShip function to onclick of every single cell? Don't you instead want to "unattach" the handler after player has clicked on 4 cells?

Comment: @pathfinder Do I declare count inside the while loop? I've tried moving the count++ inside the for loop, but that didn't seem to work either.

Comment: @stripathi I guess I don't know how to do that. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: try assigning onclick = null after you count the number of cells already clicked to be 4. Your count has to be a variable on a higher lifetime scope than the function that subscribes/unsubscribes event. I'd pull up an example but I'm too tired for it right now. Will post an answer tomorrow if no one else does.

Comment: @stripathi I tried to add the onclick = null, but then that doesn't let me click anything at all. I'll wait for you answer, and keep trying in the mean time.

Comment: OP You want to allow user to click only 4 times, after 4 clicks user is not allowed to click anymore right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, now we have a solution that stop for 4th click on the squares:

```
function placeBattleship() {
  var $shipDisplay = $("#shipDisplay");
  var counter = $shipDisplay.data("counter");
  if(counter++ < 4) {
    $(this).css("background-color", "red");  
    $shipDisplay.data("counter", counter);
  }

}
function placeShips() {
    $("td").click(placeBattleship);
}
$(document).ready(function(){
  placeShips();
});
```

I use a div with id shipDisplay to store a data-attribute for count the clicks.

Look at the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/PEba15PSLv2LK6qjY7AD?p=preview

Comment: Thanks. I finally got it to work. I've never worked with jQuery, so this was new to me.

Comment: This works great for one ship, but how do I manipulate this to let me place one ship, then the next, then the next then the next, one at a time. I've tried adding more functions but it breaks it. Any ideas? I don't know jQuery that well...

Comment: add your logic into placeBattleship.. the code inside is just painting the square with red.

Comment: I would appreciate if you vote my answer up.. thanks

Comment: I did...my votes don't count yet. Too low of a reputation.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't you consider to use jQuery?

Look your function much shorter:

```
function placeShips() {
    $("td:lt(4)").click(placeBattleship);
}
```

You can testify on the code below:

```
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>1.1</td><td>2.1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1.2</td><td>2.2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1.3</td><td>2.3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div id="console"></div>
  <script>
  $("td:lt(4)").each(function(){
    $("#console").append("Content of "+ $(this).html() + "<br/>");
  });

  $("td:lt(4)").click(function(){
    $("#console").append("Clicking "+ $(this).html() + "<br/>");
  });
  </script>
```

...or on my Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/yNZw6ZhkNfA9E0NdQg7V

Comment: This didn't do anything.

Comment: could you post your code on [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/)

Comment: Well, it doesn't show up, but hopefully you get the gist of it: http://plnkr.co/edit/0OnnUYKnUlTGQH5oaru3

Comment: So, I removed the :lt(4) since you have some another td on another places that aren't in your battlefield. Now you can click on any squares and it will be red: http://plnkr.co/edit/PzfjnfEXIgOxS16Qt7Gx?p=preview

Comment: and of course I did lots of changes haha.. you can see you click function much cleaner too: `function placeBattleship() {
  $(this).css("background-color", "red");
}`

Comment: Okay, that's great, but I need it to stop after 4 times. This is what I've been stuck on the whole time.

Comment: After 4 squares you would like to stop clicks and painting red, isn't it?

Comment: I'll create another answer with the final solution

Answer (score 0):

You should separate priorities in your logic  and **removeEventListener** when counter hits 4 , hopefully this helps you :

```
//defined outside the function
var counter = 0;
playerCells.addEventListener("click" , placeShips );
```

Then

```
 function placeShips() {
    if(counter <= 4){
      //Move ship
      placeBattleship();

//add to counter

       counter++

}else{

//Remove click event if counter reaches 4 .

playerCells.removeEventListener("click" , doSomethingElse)

}

}
```

Comment: What do I put in place of doSomethingElse?

Comment: doSomethingElse is just another function , for an example : you can reset the game , alert the user ect...

Answer (score 0):

You question needs a bit clarification. To my current understanding, you need to move the checking of `count` to `placeBattleship`.

What you are doing is binding `click` to same `td`s 4 times, not limiting the number of event triggering to 4 times.

```
// pseudo code
var count = 4; // this is global
var currentCount = 0;

initFunc() {
  // bind click events ONCE
}

startPlacing() {
  // accept user click and place ship
  // set currentCount to zero
}

placeShip() {
  // the callback of user `click`
  // check for currentCount == count then move on (no more placement)
  // increase currentCount by 1
  // place ship
}
```

Note that after an event is triggered, the listener will not be removed. Until you `removeEventListener()` from it, it will always be listening.