# add onclick event to dynamically create element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to create list of divs,
one of the divs should like this:

```
<div onclick="myFunc(this, 'arrayValue')"></div>
```

I want to achieve it by iterating through my array and passing index value to my function. One of the solutions that worked was using `setAttribute` :

```
  for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.setAttribute("onclick", 'myFunc(this, \''+array[i]+'\')');
    myDiv.appendChild(div);
  }
```

The only problem is that this part looks really ugly: `\''+array[i]+'\')'`
Is there other way to achieve this? That would look like this or something similar:

```
    div.setAttribute("onclick", myFunc(this, array[i]);
```

---

btw. other solutions: when I used `div.onclick` the onclick attr was not visible on div (result: `<div></div>`), possibly I did something wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [onClick event in a For loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15860683/onclick-event-in-a-for-loop)

Comment: The *"...this part looks really ugly"* part makes this a better fit for Code Review.

Comment: The *"other solutions"* part would be on topic if you showed what you actually did and described what was wrong and what you mean by *"...attr was not visible"*. However, it would almost definitely be a duplicate.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: @squint Attr was not visible ==  `<div></div>`, on the other hand attr visible == `<div onclick="myFunc(this, 'arrayValue')"></div>` <- version I want to achieve

Comment: Why do you want it to be visible, and where? What difference does that make to you?

Comment: It is not that I really need to to do this this way. I am just curious. The difference: without onclick attr it won't trigger a function.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var array = ['bla1','bla2'];

var myFunc = function(value) {
  alert('click : '+ value);
};

var myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');

for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.className = 'bla';
    myDiv.appendChild(div);
  
  div.addEventListener('click', myFunc.bind(this, array[i]));
}
```

```css
.bla {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Is that you want ?