# JavaScript For Loop with Closure Causing JSLint Warning

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, jslint, jshint

I have a JavaScript script that I am writing that uses a for loop to assign `onclick` events to a series of buttons. To fix issues with the scope of `i`, I am using the following example as the base of my for loops, based upon [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15860764/5530509). I wish I knew the name for this way of creating a for loop, if there even is one.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) (function(i){
    //some code
})(i);
```

When I run my code through JSLint and JSHint, it gives a warning saying, "Don't make functions within a loop." Referring to the two for loops that are built like above. Questions that I have seen about this warning do not use a loop in the format I am using, so I don't know how they apply to this.

Why is this warning given, and is there a better way than this? Also, is there a name for this for loop format (this last part can be answered in the comments)? If this is related to the other questions, why does this format work?

Comment: If I can figure out the name of this for loop format, I may be able to better word the Question Title

Comment: That's called a [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work?rq=1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just creating a `closure` and `immediately invoking function expression`.
The `onclick` event will happen some time in future, but by that time the loop has finished it's execution & the value of `i` will be updated to the last value of `i<10`

So in this case with `closure` and `IIFE` the value of `i` will be bound and will remain in scope.

An alternative way is to use `let` instead of `var`

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  // rest of the code
}
```

the scope of let is always at block level