# Create a list of settings with Next and Previous buttons in the DOM procedurally

Tags: javascript, dom

I wanted to create a list of settings that a user can change in the HTML procedurally through javascript.

Much like this: `Quality:` `-` `0` `+`

My approach to this was making an `Option` class with a `value` property and `prev()` and `next()` methods that change the value within its range. I'm extending this class so it can be a `Range`, `Bool`, etc. This is working fine.

My issue is that I can't seem to be able to incorporate this into the HTML. My current solution works only for the last option created, the others don't trigger the `onclick` event functions, and even if they did I don't feel like this is the right approach to it. How can I make this work in an elegant way?

I have tried the solution shown [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15860683/onclick-event-in-a-for-loop) but it prevents me from accessing the class instance with `this`.

```
class UIManager {
    constructor (wrapperID, settings) {
        this.wrapper = document.getElementById(wrapperID)
        this.settings = settings
    }
    updateUI () {
        this.wrapper.innerHTML = ``
        for (let id = 0; id < this.settings.options.length; ++id) {
            let option = this.settings.options[id]

            this.wrapper.innerHTML += `
            <li>
                <div class="label">
                    ${option.name}
                </div>
                <div class="option">
                    <input id="prev${id}" class="open" type="button" value="<">
                    ${option.value}
                    <input id="next${id}" class="close" type="button" value=">">
                </div>
            </li>
            `
            let prevButton = document.getElementById(`prev${id}`)
            let nextButton = document.getElementById(`next${id}`)

            prevButton.onclick = _ => {
                this.settings.options[id].prev()
                this.updateUI()
            }
            nextButton.onclick = _ => {
                this.settings.options[id].next()
                this.updateUI()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could utilize the method that you linked to at the beginning and still reference the class instance `this` by using the [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) method.

Comment: Also, I would suggest using `()` as the empty argument signature for arrow functions. It is more commonly seen in code and easier to extend to include arguments without modifications.

Comment: @TimKlein after some fiddling I figured out your method did work nicely, but since the innerHTML of the wrapper was being overwritten for each iteration only the last events were retained.

I fixed it by adding the DOM elements using `document.createElement()` instead. Feel free to post your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Cheers! Will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The answer to the question you linked as a potential solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15860764/4362829) is usable so long as you bind the class instance member `this` to the anonymous function using [Function.protoype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind).

The code would look something like this (using the previously linked answer as the starting point):

```
for ( var i = 0; i < itemLists.length; i++ ) (function(i){ 
  itemLists[i].onclick = function() {
      // do something using `this`
  }
}).bind(this)(i);
```

You mentioned in the comments that this didn't work, but that it was related to overwriting innerHTML and not due to the binding.

Hope this gives a small part of the larger picture.

Answer (score 0):

Try closure to store the values required for functions created from inside the loop.

Something like this :

```
prevButton.onclick = (function(settings, updateUI) {
    return function() {
        settings.options[id].prev();
        updateUI();
    };
})(this.settings, this.updateUI); 

nextButton.onclick = (function(settings, updateUI) {
    return function() {
        settings.options[id].next();
        updateUI();
    }
})(this.settings, this.updateUI);
```

Comment: This approach results in the `updateUI();` call from within the closure having the wrong `this` value, so it fails when evaluating `this.wrapper.innerHTML = ''`. How can I solve for this?